# JavaScript: Toggle class with inline onClick?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to replicate the css transition [here](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php).

Similar to the example, I have created:

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('grow');">Go</span>

<div class="box"></div>


.box {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid #000;
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: .5s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.grow {
 width: 350px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/swrhho41/15/

However, this doesnt seem to work. The grow class isn't being added to the div.

Is there more JS that is needed?

Comment: No, I didnt think you needed it

Comment: Looks like your `onclick` handler is looking for a div with an ID of 'box' and you're HTML has a div with a *class* of 'box'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`box` is not an `id`. It's a class.

Therefore, your `document.getElementById` selects nothing. Simply change it to,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].classList.toggle('grow');
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swrhho41/17/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your onclick code is looking for an id : `getElementById`

Yet your div has a class not an id, change it to

```
<div id="box"></div>

<span onclick="document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('grow');">Go</span>
```

make sure to also update your css if you update it to id:

```
#box {
width: 150px;
/* etc */
```

Also if you want it to grow, make the width on the `.grow` `!important`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swrhho41/18/

Answer (score 0):

Since `'box'` is a className, you need to either set the element's ID to be "box":

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

Or update your selector to be:

```
document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle('grow')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="box" class="box">

</div>
```

you are retrieving the item by Id, so Id should be box